# Resizable web button bar component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a web component that achieves the following:

- You can append to it a list of elements (in my case `<button>` elements)
- When the element is resized such that the buttons don't fit on one line anymore, the overflowing buttons gradually get moved into a dropdown on the right until everything can fit on one line again

What I am describing is similar to the Bootstrap responsive navbar (where the buttons in the header get moved into a dropdown when the screen width falls below a certain threshold):
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

However, with two big differences:

- This needs to respond to the parent's size modification (a DOM element), and not the whole browser window
- The buttons need to be gradually moved into the dropdown (not all at once as it happens with the above navbar once it goes past a specific screen width)

Here's a sketch of what it might look like:
[button bar example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv2Qv.png)

And some example HTML:

```html
<div id="parent" style="width: 50px">
  <button-bar style="width: 100%">
    <button>hello 1</button>
    <button>hello 2</button>
    <button>hello 3</button>
    <button>hello 4</button>
  </button-bar>  
</div>

<!-- because the above 4 buttons would not fit on a 50px line -->
<!-- resulting HTML should look something like below -->

<div id="parent" style="width: 50px">
  <button-bar style="width: 100%">
    <button>hello 1</button>
    <button>hello 2</button>
    <dropdown-button>
      <!-- these buttons would be hidden until the dropdown button is clicked to reveal a popover -->
      <button>hello 3</button>
      <button>hello 4</button>
    </dropdown-button>
  </button-bar>  
</div>
```

Is there any existing library that achieves this functionality?
Any suggestions to achieve something similar that doesn't involve polling for the parent's size every few millis?